# EF6 deleting detached child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When saving an entity with child entities, the child entities are deleted from the database despite being detached.

The code is as follows:

```
if (ChildEntities != null)
{
    foreach (var child in ChildEntities)
        context.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

I also tried EntityState.Unchanged and setting ChildEntities = null before save, but either way the child entities are gone from the database after SaveChanges.

I've run out of ideas and couldn't find anything useful, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Comment: It seems that you have enabled cascade delete, could you post here your models and configurations? Check this section in manual - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, I didn't make this clear, but I'm not deleting anything, just saving input changes - the parent entity is set to EntityState.Modified (I tried setting it before and after detach, no difference). So no delete action should be triggered whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, then there is another question - why do you detach `ChildEntities`? Do you want to keep them unmodified or why? Cascade delete rules are also applied in entity modification. So if you set `ChildEntities` to `null` and update parent entity it will delete old `ChildEntities`. And `EntityState.Detached` will be probably the same case. The child entities are not tracked by context, so EF probably thinks that there are no `ChildEntities` and makes a delete. I didn't try it so it is just a guess...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the reason, they remain unchanged in this particular scenario and there's no need to include them in the save. I tried EntityState.Modified as well, but they're still getting deleted.

Comment: This must be related to things you do elsewhere, so we need to see more code to be able to help.